# How to get back formula after applied vlookup using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have vba script which apply vlookup from one excel file another file. Its work fine but the output excel file only contains output data but i need formula for that vlookup output because i need apply same thing next by using copy paste so i need a help to get formula also in output excel. This my vba script

```
Sub vloo()    
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim user As String
  Dim file As String
  Dim n As Integer
  Dim m As Integer
  Dim c As Integer
  Dim a As Variant

  n = 1
  m = 0
  c = 2

  file = "E:\output8.xls"
  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file
  Set nb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
  Set ns = nb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  'get workbook path
  filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xls", Title:="Please select a file")

  'set our workbook and open it
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)
  'set our worksheet
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  'set the range for vlookup
  Set rng = ws.Range("F:AI")

  For y = 6 To 20
    m = m + 1
    user = MsgBox(ws.Cells(1, y), 4, "You Want This")
    If user = 6 Then
      ns.Cells(1, n) = ws.Cells(1, y)
      ns.Cells(1, n).Interior.Color = vbYellow
      n = n + 1
      If m > 1 Then
        ns.Cells(2, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ns.Cells(2, 2).Value, rng, m, False)
        c = c + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

After execute this script and went to output excel ns and press F2 in each entry but getting only data dont know why formula are not there so i need formula also.

Answer (score 2):

Simply alter your script so that it writes the formula rather than the *evaluation thereof*:

Change this:

```
ns.Cells(2, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ns.Cells(2, 2).Value, rng, m, False)
```

To this (revised to fully qualify the range used in the VLookup's third argument):

```
ns.Cells(2, c).Formula = "=VLookup(" _
                             & ns.Cells(2, 2).Value & "," _
                             & "[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & "," _
                             & m & "," _ 
                             & "False)"
```

If you debug, assuming I did not make any typos, then the that should have the third argument like so:

```
[Mains_heet_for_SEA_October14.xlsx]'Sheet1'!$F$2:$M$2
```

Note this may slow down the macro since formulas may re-evaluate during runtime. There are ways around this using the `Application.Calculation` property if that becomes an issue.

**UPDATE**

You can verify this works in principle with a `Debug` statement. Put it in it's own procedure if you'd like, and test it out like so:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim m As Integer

m = 3

Set rng = Range("A1:D10")

Debug.Print "=VLookup(" _
            & "some_value" & "," _
            & "[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & "," _
            & m & "," _
            & "False)"
End Sub
```

Here is proof that this works:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but output didn't get because the address source file not available in formula

Comment: Im getting formula =VLOOKUP(,$F:$AI,2,FALSE) and one time only formula is insert in cell,  while in cell second getting error run time error 13 and type mismatch

Comment: If your `ns.Cells(2,2).Value` is empty, that explains the problem with the formula. You are on your own to debug the apparent failure of the loop: you have at least two conditional `IF` statmenents inside the `For...Next` loop, which are controlling the flow of your loop.

Comment: i want to write formula like this =VLOOKUP(A2,[Mains_heet_for_SEA_October14.xlsx]Sheet1!$F$2:$M$2,2,0) but i tried with value in ns.cells(2,2).value, even-though im getting =VLOOKUP(2140696606,$F:$AI,2,FALSE) the address is missing in vlookup formula.

Comment: ahhh ok I see. You need to include the Worksheet name and Workbook name in the formula... See revision, it is a simple fix :)

Comment: I am tried like this...ns.Cells(2, c).Formula = "=VLookup(" _
                             & ns.Cells(2, 2).Value & "," _
                             & wb & "!" _
                             & rng.Address & "," _
                             & m & "," _
                             & "False)"
Getting error.

Comment: Yeah you're missing half of the stuff needed to fully-qualify the range address. You have `wb` but what you need is `wb.Name`. You also need the worksheet name. Then you need to enclose the book name in square brackets, and the sheet name with single-quote (just in case the sheet name may include spaces).  I did that above in my revised answer. Cheers.

Comment: I am getting expected:End of statement in your revision answer .please check and correct.

Comment: Try now, there was a missing ampersand. Here is a link that might help you with basic debugging in the future: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Please, again I am getting error inside vlookup Run time error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: You want me to just delete my answer?

Comment: Sorry for trouble, I am new to vb scripts that's why lot of silly doubts.

Comment: Its working for me also in debug.print but when assign to this formula into cell[ns.Cells(2, c).Formula=] only getting error without assign work fine.

Comment: What sort of value is in `ns.Cells(2, 2)`? Also, would you use the `ns.Cells(2,2).Address` in the Vlookup (to preserve the formula better)?

Comment: Try getting rid of the single quotes within the VLOOKUP string. I thought those were needed, but now that I test it out I think that might be the problem.

Comment: You can also try using `rng.Parent.Parent.FullName` instead of `rng.Parent.Parent.Name`. It's getting late here (midnight). I might check back in the morning.

Comment: In ns.cells(2,c) only formula are save and ns.cells(2,1) or A2 cells is lookup value its same all column (2,2),(2,3),(2,4)..etc. I tried with rng.Parent.Parent.FullName but same error.

Comment: I am getting another issue if file name or file path contain ' symbol means, this should be replace two time times in vlookup formula then only vlookup working correctly so that only i am getting error.Is there any method avoid this?

Comment: Yes but I'm done debugging this for you :) you need to learn string concatenation principles, how to use basic string functions, and basic debugging skills. I'm sorry but I just can't respond to a never-ending series of followup questions every time you encounter another condition that you haven't yet learned how to handle.